# Find and Tar multiple files while keeping original names

Tags: unix, ksh

I want to find several directories, and make each one a Tar. My current find command sends the filenames to a file for logging.

```
find ${SRC_DIR} -name ./* -level 0 -type d -mtime +14 -exec basename {} \; >>${FILE}
```

This works fine. Now I want to take each of the files that I found and Tar them all, so that they're named OriginalFileName.tar.

Is there a way to do this all in one command, and how do I get the Tar files to have the original filenames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help your problem:

```
for i in $(find ${SRC_DIR} -name ./* -level 0 -type d -mtime +14 -exec basename {} \;); do tar -cvf $i.tar $i; done
```